# I am unable to run any git commands ("not a git repository" error)

Tags: git, repository, ini

I have a local project, and I use git for version control. Nothing is pushed online, everything is on my PC.

Until today, everything worked as it should. Today, I tried to enter `git status`, and I got the following message:

> Fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)

I have also tried other commands as `git add .` but nothing works. I have checked, and there is .git folder, with files and folders inside it.
Then, I tried, `git init`, but I got the following message:

> Reinitialized existing Git repository in...

Just to make sure, I opened the folder where the .git folder is, I right-clicked, and selected Git bash here..., So I must be in the right folder.

I don't mind losing changes I've made so far, but I would like to have working git, without the need to copy everything to a new folder, if possible.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: hmm, its hard, if you are ok with it, perhaps you can reinitialize the git by deleting the `.git` folder then do `git init` again... but [thats weird](https://prnt.sc/pf5qs6) that you cant `git status`, unless the head is lost somewhere..

Comment: One quick fix, create a repo in github, clone the empty repo and put everything in cloned repo. Then push the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bagus Tesa suggested, I've completely removed the .git folder and initialized a new one with `git init`.
All previous data is removed, but at least everything works now.